# Python pandas: fill a dataframe row by row

Tags: python, dataframe, row, pandas

The simple task of adding a row to a `pandas.DataFrame` object seems to be hard to accomplish. There are 3 stackoverflow questions relating to this, none of which give a working answer.

Here is what I'm trying to do. I have a DataFrame of which I already know the shape as well as the names of the rows and columns.

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['x','y','z'])
>>> df
     a    b    c    d
x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
y  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
z  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Now, I have a function to compute the values of the rows iteratively. How can I fill in one of the rows with either a dictionary or a `pandas.Series` ? Here are various attempts that have failed:

```
>>> y = {'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':2, 'd':3} 
>>> df['y'] = y
AssertionError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Apparently it tried to add a column instead of a row.

```
>>> y = {'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':2, 'd':3} 
>>> df.join(y)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'is_unique'
```

Very uninformative error message.

```
>>> y = {'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':2, 'd':3} 
>>> df.set_value(index='y', value=y)
TypeError: set_value() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Apparently that is only for setting individual values in the dataframe.

```
>>> y = {'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':2, 'd':3} 
>>> df.append(y)
Exception: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True
```

Well, I don't want to ignore the index, otherwise here is the result:

```
>>> df.append(y, ignore_index=True)
     a    b    c    d
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    1    5    2    3
```

It did align the column names with the values, but lost the row labels.

```
>>> y = {'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':2, 'd':3} 
>>> df.ix['y'] = y
>>> df
                                  a                                 b  \
x                               NaN                               NaN
y  {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 5, 'd': 3}  {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 5, 'd': 3}
z                               NaN                               NaN

                                  c                                 d
x                               NaN                               NaN
y  {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 5, 'd': 3}  {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 5, 'd': 3}
z                               NaN                               NaN
```

That also failed miserably.

So how do you do it ?

Comment: Note that its quite inefficient to add data row by row and for large sets of data. Instead it would be much faster to first load the data into a list of lists and then construct the DataFrame in one line using `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)`

Comment: Why is it more efficient to create the dataset in Lists, and the seemingly duplicate the entire dataset in memory as a DataFrame?  That sounds very inefficient in terms of memory usage - and would presumably be a problem for very huge datasets.

Comment: @xApple, I think you ran into the same problem I had (for days), where I didn't understand the difference between Columns and Index - I was thinking in terms of arrays, where these could basically be row/col or vice versa, no difference.  I totally agree with you that this basic theory of how the dataframe is expected to be used, and how to generate a DF line by line (typical when reading data from another source) is remarkably unclear!

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`df['y']` will set a column

since you want to set a row, use `.loc`

Note that `.ix` is equivalent here, yours failed because you tried to assign a dictionary
to each element of the row `y` probably not what you want; converting to a Series tells pandas
that you want to align the input (for example you then don't have to to specify all of the elements)

```
In [6]: import pandas as pd

In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['x','y','z'])

In [8]: df.loc['y'] = pd.Series({'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':2, 'd':3})

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
     a    b    c    d
x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
y    1    5    2    3
z  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I see. So the `loc` attribute of the data frame defines a special `__setitem__` that does the magic I suppose.

Comment: Can you construct this in one pass (i.e. with columns, index and y)?

Comment: So if I can generate one row at a time, how would I construct the data frame optimally ?

Comment: Was expecting some variant of `df = pd.DataFrame({'y': pd.Series(y)}, columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['x','y','z'])` to work?

Comment: @xApple prob best for you to construct a list of dicts (or list), then just pass to the constructor, will be much more efficient

Comment: @Jeff Also, lol to the TOTD comment if you didn't see my reply. :)

Comment: @AndyHayden you deleted your answer so didn't see it, but lol anyhow about the whole TOTD!

Comment: @Jeff Isn't it inefficient to construct a new `pandas.Series` for every row? Wouldn't it be better to fill a pre-created series object?

Comment: What happens if the argument of a `pandas.series` must be a list of pre-computed values, instead of a dictionary which items are specified one by one? I am trying with `df.loc['y'] = pd.Series(mylist,index=df.index)` but it does not work.

Comment: what if you do not know the number of indices? Can you add as you go and not initialize index?

Comment: @amc yes, you can also do `df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']); df.loc['y'] = [1, 5, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 106):

Update: because [append has been deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["firstname", "lastname"])

entry = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
     "firstname": ["John"],
     "lastname":  ["Johny"]
})

df = pd.concat([df, entry], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me and I like the fact that you explicitly `append` the data to the dataframe.

Comment: Note that this answer needs each row to have the column name appended. Same for the accepted answer.

Comment: This works too if you don't know the number of rows in advance.

Comment: This is the best you can do if building line by line but with large data sets, even with the `ignore_index=True`, its definitely way faster to load the data into a list of lists and then construct the DataFrame in one line using `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header). It seems that pandas does some pretty heavy lifting when appending rows regardless of index processing.

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn What about appending a DataFrame to another DataFrame? Would it be more efficient to do `df_to_append = pd.DataFrame([{'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Smith'}, {...}])` followed by `df = df.append(df_to_append, ignore_index=True)`?

Comment: @Ben - I have not tested but it should be much faster to concatenate two databases, as you show, rather than adding rows one at a time. However, for small datasets the time difference may not be noticable to the eye.

Comment: not that [append is deprecated in favor of concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append)

Answer (score 49):

This is a simpler version

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('col1', 'col2', 'col3'))
for i in range(5):
   df.loc[i] = ['<some value for first>','<some value for second>','<some value for third>']`
```

Comment: just want to ask, is this CPU and memory efficient?

Comment: how do i know  df's last row so I append to the last row each time?

Comment: Compared to the other two options of  `append()` (which possibly duplicates the whole database (as you reassign to itself) on every loop iteration), and the other common option of creating two identical datastructures (a `List` and then a `DataFrame`) of the same data, this seems much more "efficient" in terms of memory usage, but speed might be another issue entirely.

Comment: Maybe you can do `df.loc[-1]`?

Comment: You can add data to the end of the DataFrame with:  `df.loc[ len(df) ] = ["My", "new", "Data"]`

Answer (score 42):

If your input rows are lists rather than dictionaries, then the following is a simple solution:

```
import pandas as pd
list_of_lists = []
list_of_lists.append([1,2,3])
list_of_lists.append([4,5,6])

pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
#    A  B  C
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  4  5  6
```

Comment: but what do I do if I have a multi index? df1 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['A', 'B']) does not work. Wrong shape. So how?

Answer (score 2):

The logic behind the code is quite simple and straight forward

Make a df with 1 row using the dictionary

Then create a df of shape (1, 4) that only contains NaN and has the same columns as the dictionary keys

Then concatenate a nan df with the dict df and then another nan df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_datav = {'a':1, 'b':5, 'c':2, 'd':3} 

datav_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_datav, index=[0])

nan_df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan]*4], columns=raw_datav.keys())

df = pd.concat([nan_df, datav_df, nan_df], ignore_index=True)

df.index = ["x", "y", "z"]

print(df)
```

gives

```
a    b    c    d
x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
y  1.0  5.0  2.0  3.0
z  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[Program finished]
```