# Populate pandas dataframe using column and row indices as variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

## Overview

How do you populate a pandas dataframe using math which uses column and row indices as variables.

### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(5), columns = ['Combo_Class0', 'Combo_Class1', 'Combo_Class2', 'Combo_Class3', 'Combo_Class4'])
```

### Objective

Each cell in df = row index * (column index + 2)

[image: Final Objective]

### Attempt 1

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40501868/5899258) solution to produce the following code:

```
row = 0
for i in range(5):
    row = row + 1
    df.loc[i] = [(row)*(1+2), (row)*(2+2), (row)*(3+2), (row)*(4+2), (row)*(4+2), (row)*(5+2)]
```

#### Attempt 2

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterating-over-rows-and-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/) solution seemed relevant as well, although I believe I've read you're not supposed to loop through dataframes. Besides, I'm not seeing how to loop through rows *and* columns:

```
for i, j in df.iterrows(): 
    df.loc[i] = i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage `broadcasting` for a more efficient approach:

```
ix = (df.index+1).to_numpy() # .values for pandas 0.24< 
df[:] = ix[:,None] * (ix+2)
```

---

```
print(df)

        Combo_Class0  Combo_Class1  Combo_Class2  Combo_Class3  Combo_Class4
0             3             4             5             6             7
1             6             8            10            12            14
2             9            12            15            18            21
3            12            16            20            24            28
4            15            20            25            30            35
```

Comment: This returns the error _AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'_.  Curious how you were able to print your results...

Comment: Yes I do mention using `.values` for pandas versions under 0.24 in a comment. Use `.values` instead of `to_numpy` @PizzaAndCode

Comment: Ah my brain misinterpreted your comment, it makes sense now. It works perfectly using ,values(). Fantastic! Thank you for the follow-up @yatu. This is a more general solution, so marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `multiply` `outer`

```
df[:]=np.multiply.outer((np.arange(5)+1),(np.arange(5)+3))
```

Comment: Python for Data Analysis 2nd Ed (ISBN 978-1-491-95766-0), pg 473 contains code similar to this. Thank you for sharing!