# Need to populate new data frame with data from old data frame after doing math

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with data that I need to compare data on two columns see picture below (I would do things like get slope, intercept, p-test, etc from two columns being compared (Log GC/L vs Active Weekly Cases).  Then I need to extract the results and put the data into a new data frame. I have included pictures of the original data frame and the new data frame. Is there a way to do this and have it automatically populate the new data frame? The new data would just be populated the length of the column.

[Original DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REtsn.png)

[New DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k82I.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of data when asking a
question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091769/python-pandas-fill-a-dataframe-row-by-row